# Deployment in Meego crashing for large Deb file

Tags: deployment, crash, deb, meego

I recently update my QtSdk to 1.2 and after that, I am unable to deploy a debian file of more then 6 mb. It gives me the following error:
16:32:02: Preparing SFTP connection...
16:32:02: Starting upload...
16:32:03: Failed to upload package: Failure
16:32:03: Deploy step failed.
Error while building project Animal101SymbianMeegov1 (target: Harmattan)
When executing build step 'Deploy Debian package via SFTP upload'

Has anyone run across this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The workaround I use to deploy is to create a link in /tmp/.deb pointing to /var/tmp/.deb and the run the deploy step in QtCreator.